# What is the effect of calling munmap in a pthread?

Tags: c, linux, operating-system

Is there any difference between calling munmap in the main thread and calling it in a pthread function?

Comment: The difference is in what else you are doing in your program. The function itself is not "aware" of which thread it is being called from.

Answer (score 2):

There is no difference.

[`mmap()` and `munmap()` are system calls](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html) that affect the virtual memory of the entire process (all the threads), but it doesn't matter which thread makes the call.

Of course these functions do not perform any inter-thread synchronization, so if there are conflicting accesses or potential data races on the memory regions in question, that's your problem to solve.